# SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF in Node- mssql OR Tedious

Tags: node.js, sql-server, tedious, node-mssql

How can we set session level **`ANSI_WARNINGS`** parameter in **`Node-mssql`**. It is fine even if there is a control in **`tedious`** driver package.

I have tried setting the parameter in database level, unfortunately the session level will override the database level. I have also tried executing the `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` query. Is there anyway we can set this at session level ?

Comment: Messing with `ANSI_WARNINGS` (or any of the other connection defaults, for that matter) is almost never the correct solution to whatever problem you have -- notably, turning it off precludes the use of indexes on computed columns. This leads to the natural follow-up question: what *is* the actual problem that you have that `ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` is supposed to solve? There's probably a better solution.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have a set of data (Bulk) loading in to stage tables. There are error occurring over truncation. Its easier to set this than checking each field the length and trim.

Comment: Truncation is only one of the problems you face if the destination types don't match your source data -- implicit conversions can give unintuitive results as well (for example, the empty string converts to the `INT` `0` and `DATETIME` `1900-01-01`, even though you'd probably want `NULL`). If you are inserting into staging tables, it's much better to arrange them to actually be able to hold your input data (that is, make columns wide enough), whether you do conversions up-front or later with a query.

Comment: All that said -- an explicit `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` command before your queries *should* work, as this setting persists. It won't work if you close and re-open the connection, or your bulk load code resets the option. If it's not working, there's likely a problem with how your code goes about it, and you'd need to post more of that.

Comment: I have all other validations like date and other field logics. We have the same requirement to truncate the data silently than throwing an error as done by ANSI_WARNINGS. Each fields can be manually checked against the respective columns and length , Is there any alternatives ?

Comment: `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` in query is not working... I have tried that multiple times. My rough guess over that is that due to the connection pooling. Not sure though

Comment: Like I said -- you cannot have `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF` as an individual query on a connection that's then closed, because the connection settings will be reset when the connection is returned to the pool. To make this work, you have to open a connection, do `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF`, then do your queries on that very same open connection. You can also use the `options.enableAnsiWarnings` setting when the connection is instantiated, per the [docs](http://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/api-connection.html#function_newConnection), but the main thing is keeping that connection.